# Logo not shade when popup shown

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, popup

I have a problem with pop up when appears it make shade to all page's element Except my two logos. It puts appears with a border around it.

this my page before popup appears:

[image]

and this with popup:

[image]

this is my code of logos:

```
    <div className="d-flex row-flex justify-content-between">

<img className="img-fluid img-center  sticky-top col-md-2 offset"   height="100px"
  width="200px" src="./images/img1.png"/> 

   <img  className="img-fluid img-center sticky-top col-md-2" src="./images/img2.png"/> 
  </div>
```

can any one tell me, what is wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to include your relevant code within the question. Likely just need to change `z-index` on something though.

Comment: i update my question, thank you and i will search about your solution. @abney317

Comment: i make  z-index equals -1 if you mean this. but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. @abney317

Comment: You have not shared enough of the relevant code within the question for me to try to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i try to delete `sticky-top` from `<img></>` element and it's work.